# Is there any alternative to Google App Engine that supports JDBC?

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, jdbc, cloud

I have heard that Google App Engine does not support JDBC (instead they use datastore). So is there any alternative to Google App Engine that supports JDBC?

Comment: please, search little bit before asking questions - there is Google Cloud SQL for this purposes https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/

Comment: The alternative to using GAE is not using GAE. What, exactly, are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: This answer is nothing more than a bit of Googling.)

They indeed use a datastore, BigTable, which you can access through JPA, JDO or a plain Java API.

But App Engine also have a Relational Database called [Google SQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/) (relying on MySQL) which you can access using a custom JDBC driver, JPA, or JDO with the [DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/api.html) implementation. But note that the direct access with the custom JDBC driver is deprecated and that you need to use the MySQL wire protocol to connect instead (thus using a standard JDBC connector). See [this documentation link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external#wireprotocol) for more information.

Here is also a non exhaustive list of alternative PaaS supporting JDBC : [CloudBees](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/Main/CloudBees+Platform+End+to+End+Tutorial),
[AppFog](https://www.appfog.com),
[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com),
[Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/)